# What is the best way to get the absolute link of an <a> tag using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<a href="3.html">No. 3</a>
```

JS:

```
$('a').attr('href') // would return the string "3.html"
```

How can I get the string of the full path:

```
$('a').fullLinkAttr('href') // returns https://www.example.com/3.html
```

Comment: You know about `window.location`, right? Turning a relative URL into an absolute one is pretty much just "add one to the other".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans what about already absolute URLs, or ones that refer to other sites?

Comment: @code... you check the href, if it has a protocol, done. If not, you tack it onto window.location?

Comment: `.href` = done. See my answer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's not true. `window.location` can be completely different than the document's base URI.

Comment: while true, `<base>` is pretty rare (he said, running a site that relies on `<base>` for localisation purposes). Are there other situations in which it would be?

Comment: I wouldn't call <base> "rare" no, according to [Chrome's metrics](https://chromestatus.com/metrics/feature/popularity#BaseElement) it's on 16.4% of all web pages, above `window.scrollY`, and yes, there is also a Content-Location HTTP header that could change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the `.href` solves the problem easy:

```js
const a = document.getElementById("a"),
  b = document.getElementById("b"),
  c = document.getElementById("c");
  
console.log("A:", a.href);
console.log("B:", b.href);
console.log("C:", c.href);
```

```html
<a href="/t/hello" id="a">A</a>
<a href="hello.html" id="b">B</a>
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/testing..." id="c">C</a>
```

Or a pointed out by *Kaiido* in the comments one could use the URL constructor:

```js
const absolutePath = new URL("/absolute/or/relative/url", document.baseURI).href;
```

With jQuery:

```js
const absolutePath = new URL($("a").attr("href"), document.baseURI).href;
```

Comment: this is the way thanks

Comment: Would probably be useful to show the jQuery way to do this, since OP was apparently using it. (`$("a").prop("src");`). Also, this answer could maybe benefit from a note about the `URL` constructor, which allows to resolve URLs against a base URL (`new URL(path, base)`, so `new URL($(a).attr("href"), document.baseURI).toString() === a.href.toString();`

Comment: @Kaiido yes. It would be `new URL($(a).attr("href"), document.baseURI).href`. Feel free to post a second answer, or if you want me to I can edit the answer.

Comment: Go ahead, that's just a note, not worth its own answer.

Comment: @Kaiido just `$el[0]` would do great.